# Custom client-side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to check whether a username entered is already used or whether it is available. I have used the `Remote` attribute from `System.Web.Mvc` and it is working fine. I was basically using this [link](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/check-instantly-if-username-exists-asp-net-mvc-remote-validation) for reference.

However, I wonder if the same can be implemented using a button click on the form without submitting the form.

I am asking this because I want to show an error message if the name is already used and I also want to show another message if it is available (like ***"Username Available"***).

Is there any way to do this?

I'm using MVC 4 on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Unclear what you wanting. Using the `[Remote]` attribute means the form is NOT submitted (when you tab out of the textbox, an ajax call is made to you controller method which returns a value indicating if its valid or not).

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke, I want to basically do the same thing. But I want to add two functionalities.

1. I want to show a message on the page if the indicated value is valid.
2. I want to change the style of the message shown (like color, font size, etc.)

Comment: Why do you want to add a message "Username Available"? (awful user interface, and what makes you think your users will bother clicking the button anyway). If you do want to do this, remove the `[Remote]` attribute and handle the buttons `.click()` event and make an ajax call to a controller method (passing the value of the `UserName`) and return a message which you can then display in the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke: The user interface is not my idea. I'm just doing the work. Think of it as a functionality during the testing phase, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I solved this. A huge thanks to @yohanis for helping out with the basic here. I found slight errors in the code, otherwise it worked fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnCheckUserName").click(function() {
    var userName = $('#txtUserName').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'home/IsUserNameInUse',
      data: {
        userName: userName
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
          //do something
        } else {
          //display your err message here
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make ajax call to your controller action on button click (Jquery) and check your response on success and display your error message.

```
$("#btnCheckUserName").click(function () {
var userName = $('#txtUserName').text;
$.ajax({
    url: 'home/IsUserNameInUse',
    data: { userName: userName },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.exists === true) {
            //display your err message here
        }
        else {
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

});

Of course you need to define a controller action called IsUserNameinUse that takes a string variable userName.
Let me know if you have difficulty defining the action.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried this (changing the name of the stuff of course) but it doesn't work. It's not even sending anything to the controller.

Comment: Glad I'm able to help you out with this. I saw above that you are able to use the solution I provided.